# Am I on the right track to proving this statement about composite function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $F$ be the sets of all functions from $S$ to $S$.

Now I think this statement is true:

$\forall f \in F , \exists g\in F$ so that $(g \circ f)(1) =2$

I suppose $f \in F$, and I need to show that $\exists g\in F$ so that $(g \circ f)(1) = 2$

Do I just make an example  of $g$ so that $(g \circ f)(1) = 2$ ?

Like $f(1) = y$  and then  $g (y)=2 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply design a function $g$ such that $g(x)=2$ for all $x\in S$. Now since $f\in F$, we know $f(1)\in S$, hence the composition is 2. As f is arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Comment: In other words, you can also invert the quantifiers and write $\exists g$ such that $\forall f, g(f(1)) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just define a function $g$  which takes $f(1)$ to $2$ and then define the rest if images to make $g$ a well defined function from $S$ to $S$